# Toolbar default style and Navigation Icon

Tags: android, toolbar, android-appcompat

I have a `Toolbar` inside an `AppBarLayout`.
Here is the XML of both views :

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbarlayout"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/App.ThemeOverlay.Toolbar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

With the theme :

```
<style name="App.ThemeOverlay.Toolbar" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>
```

And the Theme applied to the `Activity` :

```
<style name="App.Theme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

Now, I want to apply a custom `titleTextAppearance` for the toolbar.

I know that I can use `app:titleTextAppearance` in my layout's XML but I want to configure it from the theme so that every Toolbar of my app will have the same style without setting the text appearance in every layout.

After a bit of digging in AppCompat source code, I found that `Toolbar` uses the `toolbarStyle` of the current theme as its default theme.

The default value of this style is `Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar`.

So my first guess is to override this style in my theme overlay, and change the `titleTextAppearance` in this new style :

```
<style name="App.ThemeOverlay.Toolbar" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/App.Style.Toolbar</item>    
</style>

<style name="App.Style.Toolbar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="titleTextAppearance">@style/App.TextAppearance.Toolbar.Title</item>
</style>

<style name="App.TextAppearance.Toolbar.Title" parent="TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item> (this is some green)
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
</style>
```

This actually overrides the `titleTextAppearance` of my toolbar but it's also breaking the navigation icon :

[image: Toolbar Style Fail]

What is wrong with my configuration that breaks the navigation icon ?

For the record, I tried to remove the `toolbarStyle` of the theme overlay and used directly in the layout's XML of the toolbar `style="@style/App.Style.Toolbar"`.

This correctly applies the title text appearance and it's not breaking the navigation icon, but this is not optimal as I would have to apply the style to every toolbar of my app, and that's what I'm trying to avoid from the beginning.

Thanks for the helps,
Pierre

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your default style should extend `Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar`, not `Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar`. After that it will work just fine.